# Using scala breeze with complex datatypes

Tags: scala-breeze

What is the best way to build a dense matrix within Breeze that is made up of object with different data types?

For example how would

```
case class X ( a1:Int, b2:Long, c3:Double, d4:Double)
```

get mapped into a dense matrix?

Is there an equivalent of Numpy's [dtypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) within Breeze?

Ultimately I have many millions of records I'm trying to process and am looking to perform arithmetic functions on the **b2, c3 and d4** columns based on slices on the **a1** column in the **X** class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze doesn't support that kind of functionality yet. It's desired, but there's nothing at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, one work around I saw that I may end up going with is creating a class such as - case class X ( a1:DenseMatrix[Int], b2:DenseMatrix[Long], c3:DenseMatrix[Double], d4:DenseMatrix[Double]). Then building arithmetic functions based on index lookup across the different DenseMatrix.